# How can create two TextViews, which pointing to first and last points on the chart?

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, mpandroidchart

I'm using the MPAndroidChart for drawing chart in my app. But I ran into a problem. I do not know how to draw these two TextViews, pointing to the first and last points on the chart. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

[image]

Comment: you haven't provided any code so it will be very hard to help. have you tried looking at this? https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/IMarker-Interface

Comment: @TomerShemesh
Thank you for answer! Is it possible to create two different IMarkers? For first and last points in the chart (it's markers must be visible for all time) and for clicked point  by user?

P.S. Yes, I created marker for clicked points (On the picture this marker show money and date)

Answer (score 0):

You can use marker views to implement this:

First of all add java class CustomMarkerView in your project and write below code in it.

```
package maniac.professionalchartsfree.Utilities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.MarkerView;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Highlight;

import maniac.professionalchartsfree.R;

/**
 * Created by saad.rafique on 1/5/2018.
*/

public class CustomMarkerView extends MarkerView
{
private TextView tvContent;

public CustomMarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource, int valueSize, int valueColor)
{
    super(context, layoutResource);
    // this markerview only displays a textview
    tvContent = findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
    tvContent.setTextSize(valueSize);
    tvContent.setTextColor(valueColor);
}

// callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
// content (user-interface)

@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight)
{
    tvContent.setText("x: " + e.getX() + "\n" +"y: " + e.getY()); // set the entry-value as the display text
}

}
```

After that create a custom_marker.xml file in your layout folder and write following code in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="75dp"
android:layout_height="75dp"
android:background="@drawable/markers_bg"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

After that add method in your activity where your are creating chart:

```
public CustomMarkerView markerView(Context context)
{
    CustomMarkerView mv = new CustomMarkerView(context, R.layout.custom_marker, 16, Color.WHITE);
    mv.setOffset(- mv.getWidth() / 2, -mv.getHeight()-25);
    return mv;
}
```

After that add following lines:

```
    lineChart.setDrawMarkers(true);
    lineChart.setMarker(markerView(context));
```

Now run your project and when you click point of your line chart you will get what you want.

Now you have to set this marker view for your first and last point manually by giving these values to marker view so that marker view remains there without clicking that.